# Dependency injection of Pojo classes

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger-2

At the moment I'm trying to understand dependency injection. Let's say I have following classes:

**Album**

```
public class Album {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String cover;
    private Artist artist;
}
```

**Song**

```
public class Song  {
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private Artist artist;
    private Album album;
}
```

**Artist**

```
public class Artist {
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

So `Song` depends on `Album` and `Artist` and `Album` depends on `Artist`. Let's say I get all requiered fields from a database. Currently all members are passed in through the constructor. Normally I would create e.g the same album object multiple times (in a loop for each song of the same album). Is this something that can be avoided with dependency injection?

How would I do this with Dagger2? I do not really get the point about this. Is this only "moving the constructor" out of the class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use Dagger to create your model classes you're definitely doing something wrong.

In theory this is possible, of course. You would still need a loop, but now you would create your components and pass in the arguments so that they can create their `Artist`, their `Album`, and their `Song` respectively. An `ArtistComponent` that supplies its `Artist` to the `AlbumComponent`, etc.

In the end you still have a loop, but this time just creating components to create the objects you need. The only thing you gained here is a lot of overhead and a lot more object creations than before. So no, please don't use Dagger here.

---

Dependency Injection is intended to link your business logic together. If you have an `ArtistDao` that reads from the database you might also have an `ArtistPresenter` that requires said DAO to work. The ArtistDao still reads and creates the artists (data models), but you could use Dagger to create the DAO and pass it to the presenter.

> Is this only "moving the constructor" out of the class?

Dagger does not magically create objects. If you have a dependency you still declare that dependency in your constructor. Dagger will call the constructor with the correct parameters *for you* and possibly keep the created object around for later (scopes).

Dependency Frameworks are intended to reduce boilerplate, where you create one object, pass it to the next one, etc. They will resolve your dependencies, and keep them around.